# Add Ellipsis in PHP Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

```
.
//Prev
. 
for($number = 1; $number <= $num_pages; $number++)
{   
    if($page == $number)
    {
        $navigator .= "<b>[$number]</b> ";
    }
    else
    {
        $navigator .= "<a href='?c=".$_SESSION['cID']".&rows=".$per_page."&page=$number'>$number</a> ";
    }
}
.
//Next
.
```

This is the snippet that prints number of pages.

*Sample output:*

Previous 1 2 3 4 **[5]** 6 7 8 9 10 Next

5 is the current page.

**Problem:** page numbers are shown in sequence with no restrictions. If i have 100 pages, all numbers show up.

**Question:** I need my paging numbers appear as the following...

**Assume we only have 7 ($num_pages) pages:**

Previous 1 2 **[3]** 4 5 6 7 Next

***Assume we have 90 pages:***

**[1]** 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... 90 Next

***Assume user clicked the 7th page:***

Previous 1 ... 5 6 **[7]** 8 9 10 11 ... 90 Next

***Assume user clicked 11th page:***

Previous 1 ... 9 10 **[11]** 12 13 14 15 ... 90 Next

***Assume user clicked 15th page:***

Previous 1 ... 13 14 **[15]** 16 17 18 19 ... 90 Next

***Assume user clicked 90th page:***

Previous 1 ... 84 85 86 87 88 89 **[90]**

*Any help will be appreciated.*

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're no novice in this site, you know we HELP you code, not CODE FOR YOU

Comment: I didn't request for exact solution ... Related resources, short pseudo-code or tips are sufficient.

Comment: I put together a simple PHP ellipsisizer for exactly this purpose. It is available on github, and I have explained it in more detail on my blog <http://bendalziel.com/blog.php?post_id=10195867736>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be more than enough to get you started at least

```
$count = 7; // number to show
// start at half threshold down from the current location.
$number = $current - round($count/2); 
if( $number > 1 ) echo '...';
else $ // increase to have number start at 1.
for( $number; $number < $number + $count; $number++)
{
    // your for loop as normal
}
if( $number < $total ) echo '...';
```

Comment: Solved ... http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html ... Best answer for the hint!

Comment: It seems that the `for` causes infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
$radius = 3;

for($i = 1; $i <= $total; $i++){
  if(($i >= 1 && $i <= $radius) || ($i > $current - $radius && $i < $current + $radius) || ($i <= $total && $i > $total - $radius)){
    if($i == $current) echo "<b>".$i."</b>";
  }
  elseif($i == $current - $radius || $i == $current + $radius) {
    echo "... ";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution for this kind of thing is to use "logarithmic page navigation".  See my answer to this question (PHP code included):

[How to do page navigation for many, many pages? Logarithmic page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7835752/999120)