# pagenation ellipsis (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..... 20) in php

Tags: php

I was wondering how I could do an ellipsis where it would show the first 5 pages, then echo "...", then echo the very last page, does anyone know how I could do that? Thank you so much!

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; };
$start_from = ($page-1) * 5; 

$GrabRows = $database2->prepare("SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY `ranks`.`xp` DESC LIMIT $start_from, 5");
$GrabRows->execute();
$OverallSkills = $GrabRows->fetchAll();
$TotalCount = $GrabRows->rowCount();
$TotalPages = ceil($TotalCount / 1);


$RankNumber = (intval($_GET["page"]) *5) -4;
foreach($OverallSkills as $row){
//dowork
$RankNumber +=1; //rank for the table, irrelevant at the moment.
}


for ($i=1; $i<=$TotalPages; $i++) {  
echo "<li class=\"current\"><a id=\"paginationListItem$i\" href=\"?page=$i\">$i</a></li>\n"; //$i is the page  it's adding (each time it loops the page is +1)
echo "\n"; 
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add Ellipsis in PHP Pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131517/add-ellipsis-in-php-pagination)

Answer (score 2):

**This code does the job:**

```
<?

$max = max($TotalPages, min($TotalPages, 5));
for ($i=1; $i<=$max; $i++) {  
    echo "<li class=\"current\"><a id=\"paginationListItem$i\" href=\"?page=$i\">$i</a></li>\n"; //$i is the page  it's adding (each time it loops the page is +1)
    echo "\n"; 
}

if($totalPages > 6) {
    echo "<li>...</li>\n";
}

if($totalPages > 5) {
    echo "<li class=\"current\"><a id=\"paginationListItem$totalPages\" href=\"?page=$totalPages\">$totalPages</a></li>\n";
    echo "\n\n"; 
}

?>
```

There are 2 if statements, because you don't want to display `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 6`.

With 6 pages, this code displays `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, and with 7 pages `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 7`.

Comment: That works, but it's creating 5 pages instead of the amount of pages overall. so if I have 2 pages, it creates 5 pages even though there isn't 5.